# howtodeploy dotnetnuke webapplication in webserver

Tags: webserver, dotnetnuke, web-applications

I created one dotnetnuke web application and also i worked with the database aslo, now i want to deploy in my webserver as a portal. How to deploy the dotnetnuke web application in my web server, I want the steps how to deploy the dnn application..

Answer (score 1):

It depends because there are numerous scenarios.

A. Simple solution is to just copy DNN and its database to web server, as you can do with any other asp.net application. This is good option if you need to move all you have locally.

1. Copy file system with local dnn to web server
2. Restore dnn database to database server accessible to web server
3. Update PortalAlias table with webserver domain name
4. Update connection string(s) in web.confg to new database location.

(http://www.dotnetnuke.com/tabid/825/EntryId/1293/Default.aspx)

B. More sophisticate options is If your app is made as one or more DNN modules. Than you need to create DNN module deployment package (ZIP file with DNN manifest files, acsx files, dlls, resources, SQL install scripts, etc…).  Easy start is Create Module Package option in Module Definitions. When you have correct and complete module package you can install it to other DNN host installations.

adefwebserver.com/DotNetNukeHELP/DNN_PackageModule/

Answer (score 0):

If you will be deploying to a web "farm" (more than one server), this documentation from DNN can help http://www.dotnetnuke.com/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=uBK3uGIYYXg%3D&tabid=478&mid=857